# get Client IP in a flask based application

Tags: nginx, flask, clientip

I have Flask application deployed in server. and we are using Nginx. nginx setup is as below:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_read_timeout 25s;
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
```

In Flask setup I have done the following :

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder=None)
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)
```

Now, whenever user visits a site, I want a real ip. Currently I am getting

> 127.0.0.1

I have tried like below:

```
if request.headers.getlist("X-Forwarded-For"):
    ip = request.environ['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']
else:
    ip = request.remote_addr
```

Could anybody guide me here please.

Answer (score 7):

Use `request.access_route`

https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/wrappers.py

```
@cached_property
def access_route(self):
    """If a forwarded header exists this is a list of all ip addresses
    from the client ip to the last proxy server.
    """
    if 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR' in self.environ:
        addr = self.environ['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'].split(',')
        return self.list_storage_class([x.strip() for x in addr])
    elif 'REMOTE_ADDR' in self.environ:
        return self.list_storage_class([self.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']])
    return self.list_storage_class()
```

Example Nginx config:

```
location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol https;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

Comment: @Pradeepb Can you check if you have the correct Nginx settings.

Comment: As you can see from my settings: I dont have these two entries. Should I put these two??
``proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol https;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;``

Comment: Taken to [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166044/flask-client-ip)

Answer (score 1):

You should just have:

```
ip = request.access_route[-1]
```